# Spring Java Maven Project + Module Design

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to convert an existing java project into maven project. I have the following approach in mind, but I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction.

The 1st approach is to group all the entities, repository, service, constants, implementation classes into 1 single maven module/project.

The 2nd approach is to have all the service classes in their respective maven module/project and the rest of the entities, repository classes into a base-module.

Which approach should I go for?

Approach 1

```
finance-module
 - com.example.finance.entities 
 - com.example.finance.repository
 - com.example.finance.service

order-module
 - com.example.order.entities
 - com.example.order.repository
 - com.example.order.service

code-module
 - com.example.code.entities
 - com.example.code.repository
 - com.example.code.service
```

Approach 2

```
finance-module
 - com.example.finance.service

order-module
 - com.example.order.service

code-module
 - com.example.code.service

base-module
 - com.example.finance.entities  
 - com.example.finance.repository
 - com.example.order.entities
 - com.example.order.repository
 - com.example.code.entities
 - com.example.code.repository
```

Comment: approach1... your modules will be loosely coupled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach you have is a classic case of having folders by feature vs the second approach where you have a kind of folders by type (should i call it that way). Although both approaches have  pros and cons , a personal choice is to have the modules organized by feature (approach-1).

Here is my 2 cents as to why :

a) As the size of application grows , going to a specific file is a problem when there are many packages. In short a navigation problem.

b) You can have multiple teams working on these different modules independently and have a parent pom designed to have the child pom's / modules built for a release still maintaining code seperation

c) Modules become loosely coupled & encapsulated , chances are changes in one do not break the other builds because of the class A-> B , B->A problem